# Can I simulate a user being logged in from a WP_UnitTestCase?

Tags: unit-tests

I have some logic in my code that's based on whether or not the user is logged in. How do I test it from my WP_UnitTestCase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call wp_set_current_user($id) to make a user ID the currently logged in user.